# Git svn fetch fails on certain commits with "no such file or directory" on a mkdir. Any way around it?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I'm trying to switch a repository from SVN to Git, and I'm running into an issue with the initial fetch.  I have a large number of branches/tags in SVN, and I think I have them importing correctly, but the import keeps dying with this error:

mkdir .git/svn/refs/remotes/svn/tags/vss-labels/Max Sends 500->2000 trial patch:
 No such file or directory at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 2349

The error is always for the same tag name, but at various points in the history.  The repository has around 23000 commits in it, and this has stopped on me maybe 20 times so far.  I've managed to get around it by skipping the commit it's trying to merge and moving on, but this doesn't seem like the "right" solution.  What I'm trying to figure out is:

-Is there a way to automatically ignore the error and move on?  This import has been running for 3 days now, and I'd like to be able to run it without babysitting it as much.
-Is there a way to actually resolve the error properly?  I think it has something to do with the tag name, but changing the tag in SVN just generates a new commit, and therefore doesn't fix the history.  I'm fine if the solution is to permanently delete the tag from the old respoitory, I just need a way to erase it from the history.

I'm currently trying a second import with all the branches and none of the tags, and then manually converting the tags I need to reference particular commits, but if there's a way to import these cleanly, then I'd rather use it.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error:

```
> git svn fetch
mkdir .git/svn/refs/remotes/origin/aux: Not a directory at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 2349
```

In my case the problem is that `aux` is not a valid file/directory name on Windows. Didn't found a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this ended up being to switch tools.  I used subgit 3.0 to import the repository, and after some back and forth having to manually map the branches, it worked well.  Definitely a recommendation for anyone looking to transition.  I just used it for a one time import, and not ongoing integration, but the tools are able to do that as well.  Also, their support, even for free users, is great!